# How to SUM columns on multiple conditions in a GROUP BY

Tags: sql, t-sql, group-by

I am trying to return a list of Accounts with their Balances, Outcome and Income

```
Account            Transaction
-------            -----------
AccountID          TransactionID
BankName           AccountID
Locale             Amount
Status
```

Here is what I currently have. Could someone explain where I am going wrong?

```
select
    a.ACCOUNT_ID,
    a.BANK_NAME,
    a.LOCALE,
    a.STATUS,
    sum(t1.AMOUNT) as BALANCE,
    sum(t2.AMOUNT) as OUTCOME,
    sum(t3.AMOUNT) as INCOME
from ACCOUNT a
left join TRANSACTION t1 on t1.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
left join TRANSACTION t2 on t2.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID and t2.AMOUNT < 0
left join TRANSACTION t3 on t3.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID and t3.AMOUNT > 0
group by a.ACCOUNT_ID, a.BANK_NAME, a.LOCALE, a.[STATUS]
```

**UPDATE**

Have corrected the t2 left join syntax as per the comment below.

The output I am expecting is hopefully obvious from the question. For 6 accounts, the SQL should return 6 accounts with their Balance, Income and Outcome of that account.

The problem with the SQL I provided was that the numbers are wrong! As per the comments I think the problem stems from joining multiple times which is summing the amounts incorrectly.

Comment: Shouldn't the join for TRANSACTION t2 be on t2 as in on t2.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID ? {Please edit the question. Promoted to comment from Neil Moss' answer below}

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Since you didn't tell us [what's going wrong](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#code) (that is, describe the behavior you get in addition to describing the the behavior you expect), it's hard to say where, but there are a couple of possibilities. Neil points out one. Another is that since you join on the transaction table three times, you're pairing transactions with transactions and getting repetitions. Instead, join on the transaction table a single time and change how you sum up the `Amount` column.

```
Select
    a.ACCOUNT_ID,
    a.BANK_NAME,
    a.LOCALE,
    a.STATUS,
    sum(t.AMOUNT) as BALANCE,
    sum((t.AMOUNT < 0) * t.AMOUNT) As OUTGOING,
    sum((t.AMOUNT > 0) * t.AMOUNT) As INCOMING
From ACCOUNT a
Left Join TRANSACTION t On t.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
Group By a.ACCOUNT_ID, a.BANK_NAME, a.LOCALE, a.[STATUS]
```

You can use `CASE` expressions as a more readable alternative to the multiplications:

```
Select
    a.ACCOUNT_ID,
    a.BANK_NAME,
    a.LOCALE,
    a.[STATUS],
    sum(t.AMOUNT) As BALANCE,
    sum(CASE WHEN t.AMOUNT < 0 THEN t.AMOUNT ELSE 0 end) As OUTCOME,
    sum(CASE WHEN t.AMOUNT > 0 THEN t.AMOUNT ELSE 0 end) As INCOME
From ACCOUNT a
Left Join [TRANSACTION] t On t.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
Group By a.ACCOUNT_ID, a.BANK_NAME, a.LOCALE, a.[STATUS]
```

Comment: @outis - AFAIK, t-sql does not have a `LEAST` nor `GREATEST` function.

Comment: @Thomas: well, that sucks. Altered so as not to use them.

Comment: Provided final answer in my question. Accepted your answer however used SUM(CASE WHEN... for OUTCOME and INCOME values.

Answer (score 7):

Did you mean:

```
select 
    a.ACCOUNT_ID, 
    a.BANK_NAME, 
    a.LOCALE, 
    a.STATUS, 
    sum(t1.AMOUNT) as BALANCE, 
    sum(CASE WHEN t2.AMOUNT < 0 THEN t2.Amount ELSE 0 END) as OUTCOME, 
    sum(CASE WHEN t3.AMOUNT > 0 THEN t3.Amount ELSE 0 END) as INCOME 
from 
    ACCOUNT a 
    left join TRANSACTION t1 on t1.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID 
    left join TRANSACTION t2 on t2.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
    left join TRANSACTION t3 on t3.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
group by 
    a.ACCOUNT_ID, a.BANK_NAME, a.LOCALE, a.[STATUS]
```

Comment: Just missing the END on the CASE statement.

Comment: Upvoted but could not accept answer as my question was vague regarding the results and should have only joined on transaction table once.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure why you would need the multiple joins. Couldn't you simply do something like:

```
Select
    a.ACCOUNT_ID
    , a.BANK_NAME
    , a.LOCALE
    , a.STATUS
    , Sum ( t.Amount ) As Balance
    , Sum( Case When t.Amount < 0 Then Amount End ) As Outcome
    , Sum( Case When t.Amount > 0 Then Amount End ) As Income
From ACCOUNT a
    Left Join TRANSACTION t 
        On t.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID
Group By a.ACCOUNT_ID, a.BANK_NAME, a.LOCALE, a.[STATUS]
```

Answer (score 1):

The join for TRANSACTION t2 should be **on t2** as in `on t2.ACCOUNT_ID = a.ACCOUNT_ID`